# Square root of the operator on the product space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

Consider the space $\mathbb R \oplus L^2(\mathbb R)$ and define an operator on it

$$
\Psi = \left(
\begin{matrix}
A&B^*\\B&D
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

where $A\in \mathbb R$, $B \in L^2(\mathbb R)$, $C$ is a bounded linear operator on $L^2(\mathbb R)$ and $B^*(x) = \langle B,x \rangle$. I am looking for the square root of this operator such that

$$
QQ=\Psi
$$

## Idea

Formally, for the numbers $A, B, D\in\mathbb R$ the [2x2 matrix square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_2_by_2_matrix) can be written

$$
R=\frac{1}{t}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
A+s & B \\
B & D+s
\end{array}\right)
$$

where $\tau = A+D$, $\delta = AD-B^2$, $s =\pm \sqrt{\delta}$ and $t=\pm \sqrt{\tau + 2s}$.

However, in above case, $B$ and $D$ are not the numbers anymore. I was wondering, however, if one could use the analogy (perhaps via spectral decomposition to write operator as multiplicative one) to get the square root of $\Psi$. Many thanks.

Comment: How is $B$ defined? It seems that it needs to be an operator $\mathbb{R}\to L^2$ in the top right and $L^2\to \mathbb{R}$ in the bottom left.

Comment: It's an element in $L^2$, in the Hilbert spaces you can identify functionals with elements of $L^2$

Comment: My understanding is $\Psi$ multiplies an element of the form $(x,f)$ where $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f\in L^2$. Then the result would be $(Ax+Bf,Bx+Df)$ where now $Ax+Bf\in\mathbb{R}$ and $Bx+Df\in L^2$. If this isn't the case, could you describe how $\Psi$ acts on the space $\mathbb{R}\oplus L^2$?

Comment: Correct, so $Bf$ is the scalar product of two $L^2$ vectors and $Df \in L^2$

Comment: I suspect that you meant to have 
$$
\Psi = \pmatrix{A & B^*\\B & D},
$$
where $B^*:L^2(\Bbb R) \to \Bbb R$ is the map $B^*(x) = \langle B,x \rangle$.

Comment: Correct, edited.